# Mysql stored procedure not returning any values

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, cursor

This is the first time I am working on Mysql stored procedure I know it is a lame question please spare me for this,

is it not possible to print any value after the END LOOP statement  in MySQL procedure. If it is, how we can achieve this.
what I did for this:

```
BEGIN
    DECLARE U_movingCity varchar(50); 
    DECLARE U_state varchar(50); 
    DECLARE U_education varchar(50);

    DECLARE id2 int(10);
    DECLARE RankPoint int(10) DEFAULT 0;

    DECLARE movingCity2 varchar(50); 
    DECLARE state2 varchar(50); 
    DECLARE education2 varchar(50);

    DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id, state , education FROM user WHERE id != userid AND Enabled='y' AND Active='y';

    SELECT  state , education  into U_state , U_education  FROM user WHERE id = userid ;

 OPEN cur1;
 read_loop: LOOP
    SET RankPoint := 0;
    FETCH cur1 INTO id2, state2 , education2 ;

    IF ((state2 = U_state)) THEN 
        SET RankPoint := RankPoint + 14;
    END IF;
    IF ((education2 = U_education)) THEN    
        SET RankPoint := RankPoint + 16;
    END IF;
    //this displays 
    select RankPoint;

  END LOOP;

  //this doesn't.
  select id, RankPoint from user;
  CLOSE cur1;
END
```

Comment: shouldn't you use id2 instead of id? `select id2, RankPoint from user;`

Comment: id2 is not a column in my user table that's a var which I've declared for fetching value from the cursor

Answer (score 0):

You should use `id2` instead of `id` in your last query.

```
select `id2`, `RankPoint` from `user`;
```

Comment: id2 is not a column in my user table that's a var which I've declared for fetching value from the cursor.

Comment: @VishAl Yes but in that var you pass the value from the `cursor` which has the value of `id` in it. Have you tried the solution?